# Golang streaming image manipulation

Tags: go, image-processing

I am using go's standard library to re-encode user-supplied images to a standard format:

```
import (
    "io"
    "image"
    "image/jpeg"
)

func (imgReader io.Reader, imgWriter io.Writer) error {
    decodedImg, _, err := image.Decode(imgReader)
    if err != nil {
        return errors.Wrap(err, "error decoding image")
    }

    // whole image is currently in memory here as `decodedImg`

    if err := jpeg.Encode(imgWriter, decodedImg, &jpeg.Options{Quality: 90}); err != nil {
        return errors.Wrap(err, "failed to encode jpeg")
    }
    
    return nil
}
```

It bothers me that the entire image must seemingly be loaded into memory before I can encode and begin uploading it. I wish `image.Decode()` would give me a way to stream the parts of the image that have been downloaded into the encoder so that I could begin encoding and uploading the image before all of it is fully pulled into memory. Is this kind of streaming decode/encode possible, or is it the nature of image encoding that I need a fully decoded image before jpeg encoding will work? If I can stream it, hopefully I can be less strict about imposing size restrictions on the incoming image.

Comment: Most image formats do not support streaming. Some (PNG and JPEG) support progressive rendering, but that won't help your case. You'll have to read the full image in order to decode it before you can re-encode it.

Comment: Ah I wondered. Is there even a way to limit memory impact here? I can limit the size of an incoming file, but I feel like it could still end up being a heavily compressed jpeg that expands enormously once decoded into a raw format. How do folks mitigate this?